# jquerymobile erro de alinhamento

Tags: jquery-mobile

Oque ha de errado no meu codigo abaixo?. O block c nao esta alinhado com  o bloco a e b

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
   
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block C</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->




  </div> 

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem espaços em branco entre as suas divs, por isso uma é jogada para baixo, normalmente problemas assim também ocorrem quanto a codificação, que é facilmente alterada pelo notepad++(Utilizando a Codificação em UTF-8(sem BOM)).

**Tente desta forma:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel"> 
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block A</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block B</div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="height:60px">Block C</div></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
  </div> 
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```